# How to make Nginx redirect to 404 if subdomain doesn’t exist in localhost domain

Tags: nginx, subdomain, http-status-code-404

This is my localhost server configuration for Nginx. This is at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/development/localhost`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
      internal;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location /404.html {
      root /var/www/html/errors;
      internal;
    }

}
```

If I call `http://locahost` in URL bar, a 404 page error is shown. But should show `index.nginx-debian.html`. But if I call `http://localhost` with a valid subdomain, it works. Like that `http://users.localhost`, defined in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/development/users`.

I want to show Nginx default page if I only call `http://localhost`, `404.html` if subdomain doesn’t exist, and another any page if I call `http://localhost` correctly with a defined subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follow.

At `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/development/default`.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name *.localhost *.<host-name>;
  root /var/www/html/errors/404;

  location / {
    index subdomain.html;
  }

}
```

At `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/development/localhost`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name = localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.nginx-debian.html;

    # to URI errors caused by paths after domain
    error_page 404 /domain.html;
    location = /domain.html {
        root /var/www/html/errors/404;
        internal;
    }
}
```

I don’t know if this solution is the best, so if someone has a better solution, post here. Thanks.